# passing subordinate components as children vs. as properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've seen that it's possible to pass subordinate components to a React component either as children or as properties.

I.e. the below SSCCE exemplifies both approaches:

```
$(document).ready(doStuff);

function doStuff() {

    ReactDOM.render(
            <App1>
                <li>line 1 </li>
                <li>line 2 </li>
            </App1>, $('#app1')[0]);

    ReactDOM.render(
            <App2 child1={<li>line 1</li>}
                  child2={<li>line 2</li>}
            /> , $('#app2')[0]);    

}

const App1 = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.props.children}
            </ul>
        );
    }
});

const App2 = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        child1: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        child2: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.props.child1}
                {this.props.child2}
            </ul>
        );
    }
});
```

My questions are:

1. are there any differences between the two approaches (e.g. with respect to [cloneElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement) perhaps) ? One difference I do see is that with the props approach I can add type information about the subordinate components in `propTypes`.
2. if subordinate children are passed as properties is there an idiomatic way to indicate in the `propsTypes` attribute that they are React components rather than just any generic Javascript object?. Doing a `console.log(this.props.child1.constructor.name)` simply prints `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of `this.props.children` is syntactic sugar for container components.

But it has lots of restrictions. The problem is, it is not a regular array, not even an array at all when it contains less than 2 elements, so you need to use dedicated tools like `React.Children.map` instead of standard tools like `Array`'s `map`.

If a prop is fine for you, keep using it.